# Convert IIF to CASE - Help review conversion

Tags: sql, vb6, case, iif

I would like to ask for help reviewing a conversion I just did taking a piece of VB6 code and turn it to SQL syntax.

**VB6**

```
IIF([Type] = 1, 26, IIF([Type] = 2, 27, 28))
```

**SQL**

```
  CASE 
      WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN 26
      ELSE
          CASE 
              WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN 27
              ELSE 28
          END
  END
```

Comment: it works perfect in SQL

Comment: No need for the "inner" `case`: `CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN 26 WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN 27 ELSE 28 END`

Comment: yes i agree with @Lamak

Comment: It's correct. However, this is kind of too broad or too localized for [so]. You could have easily tested this yourself. If you know it works and just want it reviewd, I would suggest using [codereview.se].

Comment: Thank you Cory, I was not aware of the code review sub-domain, I will use it in the future for similar questions.

Comment: I also just found out that starting with SQL 2012, which is the version I am on, IIF expressions are supported, as a shorthand for CASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion is OK,  but could be made nicer. Unlike `IIF`, `case` supports multiple cases, so you could save yourself the nesting. Moreover, since all your comparisons are on the `[Type]` column, this is a great opportunity to use the shorthand syntax:

```
CASE [Type]
  WHEN 1 THEN 26
  WHEN 2 THEN 27
  ELSE 28
END
```